# Ruby: no implicit conversion of fixnum into string

Tags: ruby

Trying to solve one of the problems in Chris Pine's book. Asks users to input their first and last names, then it should display the total number of characters of both.

Here's one of many solutions I've come up with:

```
puts "First name?"
first_name = gets.chomp

puts "Last name?"
last_name = gets.chomp

total = first_name.length.to_i + last_name.length.to_i

puts 'Did you know you have ' + total + ' characters in your name ' + first_name + last_name + '?'
```

Comment: `length` returns an integer. Why are you asking to convert that to an integer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this a question? Does the code work, or are you having a problem? If the code works and you are looking for a critique, your question may be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You might want to read about [what you can ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask] a good question.

Comment: Please take the time to formulate a sentence containing the question you have.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is pretty strict about the difference between a String and an Integer, it won't convert for you automatically. You have to ask, but you can ask politely:

```
puts "Did you know you have #{total} characters in your name #{first_name} #{last_name}?"
```

You can also do the math this way:

```
puts "Did you know you have #{first_name.length + last_name.length} characters in your name?"
```

The `#{...}` interpolation only works inside "double-quoted" strings, but it does convert to a string whatever the result of that little block is. Single quoted ones avoid interpolation, which is sometimes handy.

If you do want to concatenate strings you have to convert manually:

```
"this" + 2.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

Length returns an integer (no need to convert to_i) so change your code to this:

```
total = first_name.length + last_name.length
```